# Fatal error: class 't3lib_div' not found

Tags: php, typo3

I'am creating a new TYPO3 extension.

```
$obj = t3lib_div::getUserObj('tx_myclass_category',1);
```

This declaration is inside `a .php` file in `pi1`. `'tx_myclass_category'` this class is also inside `pi1`.

This declaration causes a fatal error.

> 'fatal error class 't3lib_div' not found.'

How can I fix this?

Comment: did you included the file that contains the class

Comment: Sorry I'am new to this, so where do I include this class file ?

Comment: what is the file name that contain `class t3lib_div` and what is the filename that contains `$obj = t3lib_div::getUserObj('tx_myclass_category',1);`

Comment: Do you use TYPO3 6.x or 4.x?

Comment: There is not `t3lib_div` in `TYPO3 CMS 7`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The TYPO3 core utility class `t3lib_div` was namespaced and renamed to `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility` in version 6.0. Up until TYPO3 6.2, you can still use the old class name. From TYPO3 7 these classes are no longer available. So you need to use:

```
$obj = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getUserObj('tx_myclass_category', 1);
```

As a side note, there is an extension called "compatibility6" that brings back the legacy classes to TYPO3 7, but it is only intended to use them if you have extensions that depend on the old class name.